# Login method Customization using GINA

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, authentication, ipc

I know it's not easy to find a master in GINA, but my question is most near to Interprocess Communication(IPC), I wrote my custom GINA in unmanaged c++, I included it a method that checks for validity of a fingerprint for the user try to login, this function will call some method in a running system windows service written in c#, the code follows:

in GINA, unmanaged c++

```
if(Fingerprint.Validate(userName,finerprintTemplate)
{
    //perform login
}
```

in windows service, C#

```
public class Fingerprint
{
   public static bool Validate(string userName, byte[] finerprintTemplate)
   {
      //Preform Some code to validate fingerprintTemplate with userName
      //and retuen result
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do such Communication between GINA and the windows service, or simply between c++ written service and C# written service.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical method for communicating with a service (or most IPC that potentially needs to cross a session/desktop boundary) is a named pipe. You can use mailslots as well, but you have to deal with duplication issues because mailslot messages get duped across all installed protocols, so you need some kind of tagging system... gets kinda messy.

See the docs for CreateNamedPipe and work your way out from there. I have talked between C++ and C# using pipes: the interop got a little messy (binary messages), but its do-able. There's some sample code for C# pipes (from both sides) [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp).

The nice thing about using a pipe for your specific service to service comms problem is you can expand the design later on to support a UI if you need it.

Comment: The only caveat I'd add about the use of mailslots is that they are not securable, for inter-service communication this is frequently a deal breaker.

Comment: That's true enough. Not that I think he should use them anyway, I'm just a rabid completist when it comes to answering questions :-)

Answer (score 3):

[NISGINA](ftp://ftp.eng.auburn.edu/pub/cartegw/nisgina/nigel/nigel.html) is an open-source GINA plugin to authenticate against a NIS directory.  If you haven't already seen this, it's the only example of an open-source GINA plugin that I'm aware of.  If you haven't already, You might find it worth your while to peruse the source code for this.

Note that as of Windows Vista, [GINA has been deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.03.vistakernel.aspx) and replaced with another API called [Credential Provider Architecture.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend that you use named pipes. They are fast, easy to use from the C# side, provided you are using .Net 3.5 or higher, and relatively easy from the C++ side (with lots of examples available). And most importantly very easy to secure by applying a simple security descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if you followed the suggested "answers" and attempted the Named Pipe route? According to both [this link](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52381) and my own experience, GINA operates in a pre-authenticated (Session 0) context and any attempt to access a Named Pipe from your unmanaged C++ GINA dll will result in Error #5 "access is denied".

I believe Mailslots may be the only available Windows IPC mechanism that is actually available at that level, but I'm not even certain that will work (haven't tried.)

Comment: Oh yes, there's also no guarantee that your service will have started yet at the time the GINA dll fires. Windows services continue to start while logon is in process - the non-deterministic start sequence helps the machine feel "faster" to end users.

Comment: Your GINA runs under the SYSTEM account. This account can be given access to the named pipe just like any other account. The point about the service not having been started yet when your GINA is activated is a good one but relatively easy to get around by having your GINA wait on the service (or manually start it) as necessary.