# Login method Customization using GINA

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, authentication, ipc

**DUPLICATE**:[Login method Customization using GINA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523912/login-method-customization-using-gina)

---

Hi All,

I know it's not easy to find a master in GINA, but my question is most near to Interprocess Communication(IPC), I wrote my custom GINA in unmanaged c++, I included it a method that checks for validity of a fingerprint for the user try to login, this function will call some method in a running system windows service written in c#, the code follows:

in GINA, unmanaged c++

```
if(Fingerprint.Validate(userName,finerprintTemplate)
{
    //perform login
}
```

in windows service, C#

```
public class Fingerprint
{
   public static bool Validate(string userName, byte[] finerprintTemplate)
   {
      //Preform Some code to validate fingerprintTemplate with userName
      //and retuen result
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do such Communication between GINA and the windows service, or simply between c++ written service and C# written service.

Thanks

Comment: I think you've got a dupe here.  There are two copies of this question.

Comment: See the where it says "delete" under the tags?  Click that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical method for communicating with a service (or most IPC that potentially needs to cross a session/desktop boundary) is a named pipe. You can use mailslots as well, but you have to deal with duplication issues because mailslot messages get duped across all installed protocols, so you need some kind of tagging system... gets kinda messy.

See the docs for CreateNamedPipe and work your way out from there. I have talked between C++ and C# using pipes: the interop got a little messy (binary messages), but its do-able. There's some sample code for C# pipes (from both sides) [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp).

The nice thing about using a pipe for your specific service to service comms problem is you can expand the design later on to support a UI if you need it.